# Does gzip add integrity/crc check to a .tar?

Tags: tar, gzip, checksum, integrity

I run commands:

```
tar -cf myArchive.tar myDirectory/
gzip myArchive.tar
```

then I copy the file over a lot of unreliable mediums, and later I unpack it using:

```
tar -xzf myArchive.tar.gz
```

The fact that I compressed the tar-ball, will that in any way guarantee the integrity, or at least a CRC of the unpacked content?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`tar` itself does not write down a checksum for later comparsion. If you `gzip` the `tar` archive you can have that functionality.

`tar` uses `compress`. If you use the `-Z` flag while creating the archive `tar` will use the `compress` program when reading or writing the archive. From the `gzip` manpage:

> The standard *compress* format was not designed to allow consistency
>   checks.

But, you can use the `-z` parameter. Then `tar` reads and writes the archive through `gzip`. And `gzip` writes a crc checksum. To display that checksum use that command:

```
$ gzip -lv archive.tar.gz
method  crc     date  time           compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
defla 3f641c33 Sep 25 14:01               24270              122880  80.3% archive.tar
```

From the `gzip` manpage:

> When using the first two formats (*gzip or zip is meant*), gunzip checks
>   a 32 bit CRC.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the [gzip file format](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format) contains a CRC-32 checksum that can be used to detect if the archive has been corrupted.

Of course, while the checksum lets gzip *tell* you that the archive is corrupted, it doesn't actually do anything to help you recover the data inside the archive.  Thus, it's mostly useful for things like checking that an archive you just downloaded off the web really was downloaded correctly.

If you're actually worried about storing or transmitting your archives over unreliable media, you may want to consider using an archive format like [par](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parchive) that actually provides *error correction* in addition to error detection.  Of course, the down side of such formats is that the redundancy needed for error correction necessarily increases the file size somewhat.

Answer (score 6):

`tar` does not have an integrity check.
Example:

```
$ echo JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ > b
$ tar cvf a.tar b
$ sed -i s/JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJ/tttttttttttttttttt/g a.tar
$ tar xvf a.tar
$ cat b

tttttttttttttttttt
```

See, the content of `a.tar` archive changed, so the file `b` has completely different content, but tar did not notice this.
This is true for any tar, including tar-1.28 (latest) with both tar formats `--format=gnu --format=posix`. 
The `pax` command (alternative tar reader) `pax -r < a.tar` also does not notice archive changes.

Comment: The OP seems to be aware (or at least suspect) that `tar` (at least *without* the `-z` option) does not do integrity checking.  Also, the accepted answer states this.  The question is: does `gzip` (or the use of the `-z` option) *add* integrity checking?

Comment: correct G-Man, This could be an okay answer if it also included the gzip part and demonstrates that gzip does detect that the content has changed.

Answer (score 2):

If tar finds errors when unpacking, it will print a message and exit with a non-zero exit value. This behavior is independent from the compression algorithm used after the tar file has been created.

If you want to verify that the file was successfully sent to the destination over an unreliable link, then create a md5 sum of the file prior to sending and verify the md5 sum after the reception.

Comment: if im only interested in the integrity of the unpacked content. md5 on the tar doesnt add anything extra compared to the check tar does during unpackinng?

Comment: The integrity of the content inside the tar archive is taken care of by `tar` itself. You could add an additional layer if needed: If the tar file's integrity is verified, then the content inside the tar archive is OK, too. But all that should be taken care of by the protocol used to transfer the data in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

The PKZip package (win/dos) comes with a program called PKZipFix that can recover files from damaged archives. I have used this utility in the past, it can recover files from moderately damaged archives that would not decompress.